# Removing files from a filegroup

Tags: t-sql, filegroups

---

I am writing some T-SQL code to retrieve the file names that make up a file group so that I can remove the files and the related filegroup.

The way that I coded it is below:

```
set @cnt = (select COUNT(*) 
FROM
sys.database_files AS dbfile
INNER JOIN
sys.filegroups AS sysFG
ON
dbfile.data_space_id = sysFG.data_space_id
where sysFG.name = @FGName)

set @rep = 0
select @cnt

    while @rep < @cnt
    begin
        set @rep = @rep + 1
        set @FileName = (SELECT top 1 dbfile.name 
            FROM sys.database_files AS dbfile
            INNER JOIN sys.filegroups AS sysFG
            ON
                dbfile.data_space_id = sysFG.data_space_id
            where sysFG.name = @FGName)

        set @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE '  + @DBName
        set @sql = @sql + ' REMOVE FILE '
        set @sql = @sql + RTRIM(@FileName)
--      set @sql = @sql + ' (''' + rtrim(@FileName) + ''')'
        exec sp_executesql @sql
        print @sql
    end
```

Thought was to get the file count, then loop through the file names and remove them one by one.  The problem is the TOP 1 code and the fact that the first file of the file group is always returned.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: after you will remove the first file it will not appear in select results again

Comment: Nikita, thank you.  Is there are a way to loop through the files one by one?  Say there are 3 files in a filegroup.  The first time through I want to remove file#1, the second time remove file#2, etc.  Thank you

Comment: I suppose you already have such cycle, you just need to put your sp_executesql inside this loop